# Operations on a pair of columns whose names start with the same number

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here's a sample dataset:

```
ff <- data.frame(
  `210.sum` = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
  `210.pred.sum` = c(4, 3, 2, 1),
  `220.sum` = c(1, .9, .75, .7),
  `210.pred.sum` = c(10, 50, 30, 20),
  `180.sum`  = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  `210.pred.sum` = c(.5, .5, .9, .9),
  params = c(100, 50, 40, 30),
  params.l = c(2, 1, 4, 3), 
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

I want to perform an operation (e.g. division) on each pair of columns.

```
ff.2 <- ff %>% mutate (
  `210.prcnt` = `210.sum` / `210.pred.sum`, 
  `220.prcnt` = `220.sum` / `220.pred.sum`,
  `180.prcnt` = `180.sum` / `180.pred.sum`,
)
```

I know how to write the code, but the number of pairs will be variable, and additionally the names may change (more specifically the part of the name that is a number).

Any tip to automate these activities will be valuable to me.

Comment: I think this is a very valuable tip. So far I can't modify ```gsub``` for my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

For proper identification we rename the colum names;

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ff %>% 
  dplyr::rename_with(~stringr::str_replace(.,pattern = '\\.',replacement ='\\_')) %>% 
  transmute(across(ends_with('_sum'), ~ . /
                  get(str_replace(cur_column(), "_sum$", "_pred.sum")), .names = "div_{.col}")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('div')), ~ str_remove(., "\\_sum"))
```

```
 div_210 div_220  div_180
1  2.500000   0.100 2.000000
2  6.666667   0.018 4.000000
3 15.000000   0.025 3.333333
4 40.000000   0.035 4.444444
```

Comment: More complicated calculations are probably possible. I would like to perform such an operation instead of dividing. 
``` (`210.sum` - `210.pred.sum`) / `210.sum` ```
How to modify the code? It's about the right order of columns

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `num`bers using regular expressions,

```
(nums <- unique(regmatches(names(ff), regexpr('\\d+', names(ff)))))
# [1] "210" "220" "180"
```

then `sapply` over them your division by `grep`ing the right columns from the data.

```
sapply(nums, \(n) {n <- grep(n, names(ff));ff[, n[1]]/ff[, n[2]]}) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> setNames(paste(nums, 'prcnt', sep='.'))
#   210.prcnt 220.prcnt 180.prcnt
# 1  2.500000     0.100  2.000000
# 2  6.666667     0.018  4.000000
# 3 15.000000     0.025  3.333333
# 4 40.000000     0.035  4.444444
```

Make sure for the columns being in the right order.

---

*Data:*

```
ff <- structure(list(`210.sum` = c(10, 20, 30, 40), `210.pred.sum` = c(4, 
3, 2, 1), `220.sum` = c(1, 0.9, 0.75, 0.7), `220.pred.sum` = c(10, 
50, 30, 20), `180.sum` = c(1, 2, 3, 4), `180.pred.sum` = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0.9, 0.9), params = c(100, 50, 40, 30), params.l = c(2, 
1, 4, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```